# How to achieve this encoding in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` :

| Number | Master |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple |
| 2 | Orange |
| 3 | Pineapple |
| 4 | Strawberrry |
| 5 | Blueberry |
| 6 | Plums |
| 7 | Cherry |
| 8 | Dragonfruit |
| 9 | Iceapple |
| 10 | Litchie |

This is just a sample `df` . original dataframe has 10000 rows.
I want to denote Apple,Pineaple,Orange & Strawberry by 1,2,3,4 encoding( which happens to be the fruits with the top 4 value counts in the `df`) and rest all fruits as one encoding(5). how to achieve this
expected :-

| Number | Master |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 6 | 5 |
| 7 | 5 |
| 8 | 5 |
| 9 | 5 |
| 10 | 5 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create dictionary for top N values by counts in column `Master` by [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with [`Series.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.head.html) and use them for [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with replace not matched values to `N + 1` in [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
N = 4
d = {v: k+1 for k, v in enumerate(df['Master'].value_counts().head(N).index)}
print (d)

df['Master'] = df['Master'].map(d).fillna(N + 1).astype(int)
```

If you have list of top values by list:

```
L = ['Apple','Pineapple','Orange','Strawberrry']
d = {v: k+1 for k, v in enumerate(L)}
print (d)
{'Apple': 1, 'Pineapple': 2, 'Orange': 3, 'Strawberrry': 4}

df['Master'] = df['Master'].map(d).fillna(len(L) + 1).astype(int)
print (df)
   Number  Master
0       1       1
1       2       3
2       3       2
3       4       4
4       5       5
5       6       5
6       7       5
7       8       5
8       9       5
9      10       5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dict` and [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and [`fillna(5)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) for keys that don't exist in `dct`.

```
dct = {'Apple':1, 'Pineapple':2,'Orange':3 , 'Strawberrry':4}
df['Master'] = df['Master'].map(dct).fillna(5).astype(int)
print(df)
```

---

```
   Number  Master
0       1       1
1       2       3
2       3       2
3       4       4
4       5       5
5       6       5
6       7       5
7       8       5
8       9       5
9      10       5
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would also be to create a mapping function and apply it to your column:

```
dic = { 'col1' : [1,2,3,4,5,6], 'fruits' : ['apple', 'banana', 'tomato','something else', 'apple', 'banana'] }

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dic)

def mapping(row):

    if row == "apple":
        result = 1
    elif row == "banana":
        result = 2
    else:
        result = 5
    return result

df['fruits'] = df['fruits'].apply(mapping)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use converters option of pandas to read this csv file.

```
#creating functions to rename the columns
converter_dict = {'Apple': '1', 'Orange': '2', 'Pineapple': '3', 'Strawberrry': '4'}

def converter_func(x):
    name = converter_dict.keys()
    if x not in name:
        x = x.replace(x,'5')
    else:
        x = x.replace(x,converters_dict[x])
    return x

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', converters = {"Master": converter_func})
```

Output:

```
Number  Master
1        1
2        2
3        3
4        4
5        5
6        5
7        5
8        5
9        5
10       5
```

for more details on converters parameter you can read [medium website](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/make-the-most-out-of-your-pandas-read-csv-1531c71893b5) or in [Official Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv)